# Django Internal Server Error (takes exactly 1 argument (2 given))

Tags: django, django-forms, runtime-error

I receive an internal server error "TypeError: valid_month() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" when I try and submit this DJango form. It looks to me like I'm only passing one argument to valid_month(), not two. Will you help me understand what I'm doing wrong here? I'm using the google app engine launcher to test this.

```
import webapp2

form="""
<form method="post">
    What is your birthday?<br>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="month">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="day">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="year">
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""
```

forms.py

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def valid_day(day):
        if day.isdigit() and int(day) in range(1, 32):
            return int(day)

    def valid_month(month):
        months = {'jan':'January', 'feb': 'February', 'mar':'March', 'apr':'April','may':'May',
                    'jun':'June', 'jul': 'July', 'aug': 'August', 'sep': 'September',
                    'oct': 'October', 'nov': 'November', 'dec': 'December'}
        m = month.lower()[:3]
        if m in months:
            return months[m]

    def valid_year(year):
        if year.isdigit() and int(year) in range(1900, 2021):
            return year

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.out.write(form)

    def post(self):
        user_month = self.valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = self.valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = self.valid_year(self.request.get('year'))
        if not(user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.response.out.write(form)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("You entered a valid date")




app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

I receive the following traceback when submitting the form:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1535, in __call__
>     rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1529, in __call__
>     rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1278, in default_dispatcher
>     return route.handler_adapter(request, response)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1102, in __call__
>     return handler.dispatch()   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 572, in dispatch
>     return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 570, in dispatch
>     return method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/macuser/Documents/UdactyCS253/HelloWorld/hello/main.py", line
> 58, in post
>     user_month = self.valid_month(self.request.get('month')) TypeError: valid_month() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution will be to add `self` argument to `valid_day`, `valid_month` and `valid_year`  functions:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def valid_day(self, day):
        if day.isdigit() and int(day) in range(1, 32):
            return int(day)

    def valid_month(self, month):
        months = {'jan':'January', 'feb': 'February', 'mar':'March', 'apr':'April','may':'May',
                    'jun':'June', 'jul': 'July', 'aug': 'August', 'sep': 'September',
                    'oct': 'October', 'nov': 'November', 'dec': 'December'}
        m = month.lower()[:3]
        if m in months:
            return months[m]

    def valid_year(self, year):
        if year.isdigit() and int(year) in range(1900, 2021):
            return year

    ...
```

But, even better would be to move `valid_day`, `valid_month` and `valid_year` outside of `webapp2.RequestHandler` because, you should define class methods only if they are relevant to the class and need an instance. In your case, these helper functions are just validating date parts - they should not be defined as methods on `webapp2.RequestHandler` class. Then, call these functions without `self.`:

```
def valid_day(day):
    if day.isdigit() and int(day) in range(1, 32):
        return int(day)

def valid_month(month):
    months = {'jan':'January', 'feb': 'February', 'mar':'March', 'apr':'April','may':'May',
                'jun':'June', 'jul': 'July', 'aug': 'August', 'sep': 'September',
                'oct': 'October', 'nov': 'November', 'dec': 'December'}
    m = month.lower()[:3]
    if m in months:
        return months[m]

def valid_year(year):
    if year.isdigit() and int(year) in range(1900, 2021):
        return year

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.out.write(form)

    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))
        if not(user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.response.out.write(form)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("You entered a valid date")
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**
You are sending two requests. As you know you are sending the month, but you are also sending a request.

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html

Take a look at that link. It teaches you everything you need to know about forms and calling them.

**Solution**
I would recommend adding another parameter to your function (requests, month)

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this resource.